# Android Studio using all the CPU and becoming unresponsive

Tags: android-studio, cpu-usage

I'm not doing anything intensive with AS - just working through developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin

I've increased the ram available for AS to 4GB, but that hasn't helped. It just bogs down after a few minutes use, and I can see in the task manager that it is using up to 97% of the CPU. I've got a pretty decent laptop, 16Gb ram - and have used older versions of AS to create java apps without issues. This is my first effort with Kotlin, and first time with this version of AS.

I just have to close AS with the task manager and restart it, but I'm not getting any work done before it freezes again.

```
Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335, built on September 30, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 8
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.instant.shutdown=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.intellij.marketplace (213.7172.48)
    com.thoughtworks.gauge (213.5744.125)
    com.developerphil.adbidea (1.6.8)
```

How can I find out what's going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. It has something to do with Android Studio IDE itself sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for **Windows**:

The problem was with Android Studio itself not deleting all the folders when fresh reinstalling it. So, you must do so manually:

1. Backup your project
2. Uninstall Android Studio
3. In "Windows Explorer" enable the option "Hidden items"
4. Go to C:\Users[your_name]\AppData\Roaming\Google
5. Delete everything inside the folder
6. Go to C:\Program Files\Android
7. Delete everything inside the folder
8. Reinstall Android Studio (if prompted to import settings select "no")

If you have any other problem, comment below, and I will try to help you with the best of my knowledge.